# Can't Auto-create a Table on pgAdmin using Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, pgadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmvtG.jpg)I'm using Hibernate to Auto Create a Table on pgAdmin.
-The log is not showing any errors
-It is recognizing the existence of the db since i get an error if i delete it
-Im using dll-auto: update

I'm trying to auto create a table using Hibernate on pgadmin. Code is giving no errors but the table is not being created

Answer (score 0):

`PostgreSQLDialect` is deprecated (please refer [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html))
Please use `PostgreSQL82Dialect` or `PostgreSQL92Dialect` based on your postgres version.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/customer
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide any info about your code, I'm considerng that from code point of view every thing is fine. please check below Items:

1. Do u checking the right data base instance? if you use IntelliJ, use Database panel to check.
2. you can use below properties to check SQL commands execution in microservice logs:

```
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```